# How to insert images from geodatabase to layout in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, esri-geodatabase, reports, arcgis-survey123

I have a geodatabase downloaded from Survey123 for ArcGIS with 1.783 points with attachments (images) and I want to generate reports from the attribute table of the feature class.

I've designed a report in the layout tab using the Data Driven Pages dynamic text feature, but I have to insert the images in the report now. The images are stored in the geodatabase in a blob field format, and I don't know how to insert the graphical reference of the blob field in the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For DDP, it looks like you can use this method posted in Esri Tech Support.

[How To: Add dynamic images to a map document with attachments from Data Driven Pages](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011972)

Comment: @YagoDinali Great to hear! If you get a chance, please mark the post as answered so others know your question has been resolved. Thanks!